# transaction rolling back when belongs_to is used (Agile Web Development with rails Chapter 12 G1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the book "Agile web development with rails". And I was working on iteration G1(Capturing an Order). In there to make a connection between line_items and order the code that is used is this

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order // 1 (this line)
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end
end
```

If I remove line 1, the `line_items` are getting added. But if I keep this line, when I click the `Add Cart` button the transaction is getting rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the item should belong to the cart but not to the order (just yet).

With recent versions of Rails (i.e. since Rails 5) `belongs_to` associations are now required, and this could be causing your problem as presumably the order doesn't exist yet.

Try changing the line to this:

```
belongs_to :order, optional: true
```